# How to convert list into different format using f{} and add string

Tags: python

The list are below

```
second_list = ['C']
first_list =  ['Z A', 'Z B']
third_list  = ["D"]
```

Expected out is below

`the firstlist is Z.A,Z.B the second_list is C and thirdlist is D`

psudo code

```
print (f'the firstlist is {",".join(first_list)} the second_list is {",".join(second_list)} and thirdlist is {",".join(third_list)}')
```

Current Output
`the firstlist is Z A,Z B the second_list is C and thirdlist is D`

Comment: Are you wanting it to replace the spaces in first_list with periods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expressions in f-strings can be arbitrarily complex, including constructing another list from the one you have, where spaces are replaces by periods, and the list as a whole is converted in to a comma-separated string.

However, it's sufficiently complex that you may want to do that bit in a function, such as with:

```
second_list = ['C']
first_list =  ['Z A', 'Z B']
third_list  = ["D"]

def morph(myList):
    return ",".join([item.replace(" ",".") for item in myList])

print (f'the firstlist is {morph(first_list)} the second_list is {morph(second_list)} and thirdlist is {morph(third_list)}')
```

That outputs, as requested:

```
the firstlist is Z.A,Z.B the second_list is C and thirdlist is D
```

The advantage of putting that into a function is that there's only *one* place to change rather than three if you leave the complexity in the f-string. It also makes it more readable overall.

An example of concentrating complexity would be if you decided that *any* quantity of spaces (greater than zero, obviously) in the string should be replaced with a *single* period:

```
import re

second_list = ['C']
first_list =  ['Z    A', 'Z B']
third_list  = ["D"]

def morph(myList):
    return ",".join([re.sub(" +",".", item) for item in myList])

print (f'the firstlist is {morph(first_list)} the second_list is {morph(second_list)} and thirdlist is {morph(third_list)}')
```

With that code, you still get `Z.A` even though there are multiple spaces between the `Z` and the `A`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `replace(" ",".")` in your `fstring`:

```
print (f'the firstlist is {",".join(first_list).replace(" ",".")} the second_list is {",".join(second_list).replace(" ",".")} and thirdlist is {",".join(third_list).replace(" ",".")}')
```